# ContentType always null on ValidatePrincipal event

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

`context.Response.ContentType` always comes up null in the `OnValidatePrincipal` event. I implemented cookie authentication following [the official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x), and I'm trying to make the validation more efficient by only checking when content type is `text/html`, but it always comes up null. Why is this? Does this event fire before the header data is created?

Comment: Show us the code you wrote, and what you have tried.

Comment: `context.Response` is set when the response is being written to the client. Normally, you don't do anything once that started.

Comment: Is there never a chance to access it? The MVC 5 app I'm converting can access it in the Global.asax events, but those no longer exist.

Comment: Not sure what code to show. It's just an empty ValidatePrincipal method with a var assignment to context.Response.ContentType.

Comment: I think @CamiloTerevinto was suggesting you should be using `context.Request.ContentType`?  `OnValidatePrincipal()` is called in the request pipeline, not the response pipeline.

Comment: I didn't know that. Unfortunately, `context.Request.ContentType` is also always null.